# Problems with routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a problem with routes.rb

In my web application i have two pages with the login form

"/home/index" and "/users/index"

This is my routes file

```
  controller :home do
    get     'login'   => :index
    post    'login'   => :create
  end

  controller :users do
    get     'login'   => :index
    post    'login'   => :post_login
  end

  get "home/index"

  get "home/create"

  get "home/show"

  get "private/index"

  get "users/index"

  get "users/get_login"

  get "users/post_login"

  resources :users do
    collection do
      get  'get_login'
      post 'post_login'
    end
  end
```

the problem is that if i use login with my "home/index" it executes the right action "create" of the home controller, while if i login in "users/index" page it executes again the "create" instead of "post_login", why?

The code i used for my form in "/home/index" and "/users/index" is the same...

This is the simple form

```
<%= form_tag do %>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%= text_field_tag :name, params[:name] %>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>            
            <td>
                <%= password_field_tag :password, params[:password] %>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%= submit_tag "Login" %>           
            </td>
        </tr>
<% end %>
        <tr>            
            <td>
                <%= link_to 'Registrazione', users_index_url %>             
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

the users controller code:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController


      def index

      end  

      def post_login
        redirect_to "http://www.google.it"
      end

    end
```

Comment: can you post the code from the culprit form please, I suspect the action points to the `home/index` path for both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have users, only as resources:

```
 controller :home do
    get     'login'   => :index
    post    'login'   => :create
  end

  get "/users" => 'users#index'
  post "/users" => 'users#post_login'


  get "home/index"

  get "home/create"

  get "home/show"

  get "private/index"
```

In the only array, just add the actions that u are using...

Comment: in this way it gives this error: Unknown action

The action 'show' could not be found for UsersController, but i don't use this action

Comment: just use :only => [] in the resource then. check it out my response, i had updated it

Comment: now when i click on login button from my "/users/index" page it gives me this error: No route matches [POST] "/users"

Comment: I kind of organized better the routes.rb file, try that one. if it doesnt work, please post the code from you users controller.

Comment: i added on my first post the users controller, but it's very simple

Comment: being that controller just those 2 actions, i would add them instead of using resource. check it out my edit

Comment: the problem remains if i add another form in my page, for example a registration form. In this way how can i route in the rigth way? I added in the page "users/index" a registration form and another action in my users controller "post_registration".