# how to set routes.rb for two form in the same page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the same situation solved in part in this [question]: [Problems with routes.rb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10824412/problems-with-routes-rb)

Now I have in my "/users/index" two forms, for example, login form and registration form.
I create two different action in the users_controller, post_login and post_registration with a simple redirect to another page, but if I click on the buttons it gives me the same error: No route matches [POST] "/users"

Here is my routes.rb code

```
Mysite::Application.routes.draw do

  controller :home do
    get     'login'   => :index
    post    'login'   => :create
  end

  resources :users, :only => [:index] do
      get     'login'         => :index
      post    'login'         => :post_login
      get     'registration'  => :index
      post    'registration'  => :post_registration
    collection do
      post 'post_login'
      post 'post_registration'
    end
  end

#  get "/users" => 'users#index'
#  post "/users" => 'users#post_login'

  get "home/index"

  get "home/create"

  get "home/show"

  get "private/index"

  get "users/index"

  get "users/post_login"

  get "users/post_registration"

end
```

while here my my form_registration...

```
<%= form_tag do %>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%= text_field_tag :name, params[:name] %>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>            
            <td>
                <%= password_field_tag :password, params[:password] %>
            </td>
        </tr>       
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%= submit_tag "Registration" %>            
            </td>
        </tr>
<% end %>

    </table>
```

... and form_login

```
<%= form_tag do %>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%= text_field_tag :name, params[:name] %>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>            
            <td>
                <%= password_field_tag :password, params[:password] %>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%= submit_tag "Login" %>           
            </td>
        </tr>
<% end %>
        <tr>            
            <td>
                <%= link_to 'Registrazione', '/users/index' %>              
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying your form tags to be like below:

```
<%= form_tag('/users/post_registration', :method => :post) %>
```

for registration, and:

```
<%= form_tag('/users/post_login', :method => :post) %>
```

for login. The ':method => :post' option isn't strictly necessary but it doesn't hurt to be explicit.